# Limiting drop-down options based on lookup table

Tags: google-app-maker

I have three tables (simplified for this question):

- Teams: [team_id, team_name]
- Users: [user_id, user_name]
- Teams_x_Users: [id, team_id_fk, user_id_fk]

(Screenshot below) On an **Update User Form**, I placed a table with the selected user's assigned teams for viewing/deleting. Below that, I have a "Teams" drop-down for assigning teams from the Teams table to the user.

In its current state, the drop-down contains all available Teams (projected values).

I want the drop-down to contain available Teams NOT currently assigned to the user.

I took a shot in the dark and tried setting up a new **Team_Unselected** Datasource with the query expression `Teams_x_Users.Users.user_id != :userid`, but receive the following error:

`Cannot complete binding from query.parameters.userid to @datasources.Teams_x_Users.item.Users.user_id. Unexpected error on binding initial sync write : (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'wb' of null in Teams_Unselected (Teams)`

[image]

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to assist and is too broad.

Comment: Apologies, I have a habit of getting wordy so I specifically tried to keep it brief - whoops! I've edited the OP to add more context along with a screenshot.